# Refer to table name dynamically in DB2/400 SQL query..?

Tags: db2, db2-400, db2-luw

I'd like to run a query that gets a combination of live data and metadata for a regularly changing list of table names. This is for research & analysis on a large server with 100+ schemas and thousands of tables/views in each. I need help referring to table names dynamically, which I do understand is NOT possible. However...

My googling indicates the solution may be an SQL statement in a text variable, which is then executed by the EXEC statement. But this is DB2/400 v7r3, which is a complex thing (as is its SQL reference on the IBM web site), and I'm having difficulty creating correct syntax.

Here is a basic example of what I wish to do, but of course it does not work:

```
SELECT        TABLE_NAME,
              TABLE_TEXT,
              ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME ) AS ROW_COUNT
              -- above line of course does not work
FROM          QSYS2.SYSTABLES
WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA = 'ABCDEFGH'
AND           TABLE_NAME IN ('ARCMNTST', 'ARIMSGT', 'ARTENT', 'DAILYHT', 'ETC')
```

I understand I need something like the following, but I cannot figure out the correct statements:

```
DECLARE       @sqltext AS VARCHAR(128)
SELECT        TABLE_NAME,
              TABLE_TEXT,
              ( SET @sqltext = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ABCDEFGH.' || TABLE_NAME
                EXEC sqltest ) AS ROW_COUNT --this is probably wrong
FROM          QSYS2.SYSTABLES
WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA = 'ABCDEFGH'
AND           TABLE_NAME IN ('ARCMNTST', 'ARIMSGT', 'ARTENT', 'ETC', 'ETC', 'ETC')
ORDER BY      TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic SQL isn't difficult...

Basically, build your SQL statement into your string variable.  Using `CONCAT` to include values from other

```
@sqlStmt = 'Insert into mytable values (''ConstVal'',' concat SomeVar concat ')';

execute immediate @sqlStmt;
```

The catch is that you have to escape strings, like 'ConstVal' above with double single quotes.

The other catch is that you can't use `SELECT` like you are trying to.  If you only had one row to return, `SELECT INTO` would be an option for a static statement.  But isn't supported for dynamic.  You have to use a dynamic `VALUES INTO` instead.

However, it appears you want to get back multiple rows.  In which case, you need to use a cursor.  Unfortunately,  dynamic cursors are a bit more complex as you have to use the SQL Descriptor.

```
declare myCursor cursor for myStatement;

set @sqlStmt = 'select ....';
prepare myStatement into mySqlDescriptor from @SqlStmt;

open myCursor;
// done if you are returning the results
// assuming you want to process in your procedure..
// add a loop that does 
//   fetch next from myCursor into myData;
```

Having said all that, you don't need any of it to get a row count for a table...the syspartitionstat catalog view already has that info.

```
select table_name, number_rows 
from syspartitionstat
where table_schema = 'ABCDEFGH' 
      and TABLE_NAME in ('ARCMNTST', 'ARIMSGT', 'ARTENT', 'ETC', 'ETC', 'ETC');
```